# Get the number of dict values in a nested dict

Tags: python, recursion

I have the following json object:

```
[{
    'firstname': 'Jimmie',
    'lastname': 'Barninger',
    'zip_code': 12345,
    'colors': ['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'],
    'ids': {
        '44': 'OK',
        '51': 'OK'
    },
    'address': {
        'state': 'MI',
        'town': 'Dearborn'
    },
    'other': {
        'ids': {
            '1': 'OK',
            '103': 'OK'
        },
    } 
}, {
    'firstname': 'John',
    'lastname': 'Doe',
    'zip_code': 90027,
    'colors': None,
    'ids': {
        '91': 'OK',
        '103': 'OK'
    },
    'address': {
        'state': 'CA',
        'town': 'Los Angeles'
    },
    'other': {
        'ids': {
            '91': 'OK',
            '103': 'OK'
        },
    } 
}]
```

I would like to be able to get the number of unique key values that each dict has. In the above, the number would be:

```
address: 2 # ['state', 'town']
ids: 4 # ['44', '51', '91', '103']
other.ids 3 # ['1', '103', '91']
```

I've been having trouble iterating of the objects to figure this out, especially if there is an item within a list. What I've been trying thus far is something like the below, though it doesn't currently work I'm pasting it for reference:

```
def count_per_key(obj, _c=None):

    if _c is None: unique_values_per_key = {}

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [count_per_key(l) for l in obj]

    elif not isinstance(obj, dict):
        pass

    else:
        for key, value in obj.items():
            if not isinstance(value, dict):
                continue
            elif isinstance(value, dict):
                if key not in unique_values_per_key: unique_values_per_key[key] = set()
                unique_values_per_key[key].union(set(value.keys()))
                return count_per_key(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                return [count_per_key(o) for o in value]

    return unique_values_per_key
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = [{'firstname': 'Jimmie', 'lastname': 'Barninger', 'zip_code': 12345, 'colors': ['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'], 'ids': {'44': 'OK', '51': 'OK'}, 'address': {'state': 'MI', 'town': 'Dearborn'}, 'other': {'ids': {'1': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}}}, {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'zip_code': 90027, 'colors': None, 'ids': {'91': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}, 'address': {'state': 'CA', 'town': 'Los Angeles'}, 'other': {'ids': {'91': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}}}]
def get_vals(d, _path = []):
  for a, b in getattr(d, 'items', lambda :{})():
    if a in {'ids', 'address'}:
       yield ['.'.join(_path+[a]), list(b.keys())]
    else:
       yield from get_vals(b, _path+[a])

c = defaultdict(list)
results = [i for b in d for i in get_vals(b)]
for a, b in results:
  c[a].extend(b)

_r = [[a, set(list(b))] for a, b in c.items()]
new_r = [[a, b, len(b)] for a, b in _r]
```

Output:

```
[
 ['ids', {'91', '44', '51', '103'}, 4], 
 ['address', {'state', 'town'}, 2], 
 ['other.ids', {'1', '91', '103'}, 3]
]
```

Comment: @DavidL Please see my recent edit. Note that this solution only relies on the names of the most immediate values you are searching for, not the path to the values.

Comment: thanks for the update, but for this I don't know the keys beforehand. Is there a way to apply the above without knowing the field names?

Comment: @DavidL Do you mean that the solution should be able to take a list of desired names, not have them hardcoded?

Comment: would there be a way to do it without hardcoding the {'ids', 'address'} line in there?

Comment: @DavidL Would it be an acceptable solution to simply pass the set to the function? That way the set could be defined elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

```
l= [{'firstname': 'Jimmie', 'lastname': 'Barninger', 'zip_code': 12345, 'colors': ['2014-01-01', '2015-01-01'], 'ids': {'44': 'OK', '51': 'OK'}, 'address': {'state': 'MI', 'town': 'Dearborn'}, 'other': {'ids': {'1': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}}}, {'firstname': 'John', 'lastname': 'Doe', 'zip_code': 90027, 'colors': None, 'ids': {'91': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}, 'address': {'state': 'CA', 'town': 'Los Angeles'}, 'other': {'ids': {'91': 'OK', '103': 'OK'}}}]
def find_dicts(d,parent=''):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v,dict):
            if parent is not '':
                identifier=str(parent)+'.'+str(k)
            else:
                identifier=str(k)
            yield {identifier:[x for x in v.keys()]}
            yield from find_dicts(v,k)
        else:
            pass

s=[list(find_dicts(d)) for d in l]
dict_names=[list(y.keys())[0]  for y in s[0]]
final_dict={name:[] for name in dict_names}
for li in s:
    for di in li:
        di_key=list(di.keys())[0]
        di_values=list(di.values())[0]
        for k,v in final_dict.items():
            if k == di_key:
                for value in di_values:
                    if value not in final_dict[k]:
                        final_dict[k].append(value)
for k,v in final_dict.items():
    print(k,":",len(v),v)
```

Output

```
ids : 4 ['44', '51', '91', '103']
address : 2 ['town', 'state']
other.ids : 3 ['103', '1', '91']
other : 1 ['ids']
```